# Does CrashPlan allow upload via FTP?

Tags: backup, ftp, crashplan

I've got the free version of CrashPlan and I am backing up my computers to each other. My [web hosting provider](http://torben.g-b.dk/dreamhost) allows me to use 50GB online storage for backup, and I'd like to integrate that with CrashPlan but I don't see an option to do so.

Did I just miss the setting, or does CrashPlan really not offer to put backups in an FTP location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [their FAQ](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/faq/backup#can_i_back_up_using_ftp), this is not supported:

> Can I back up using FTP?
>
> No. At this time, CrashPlan must be installed and running on the destination. We may support FTP at some point, but it would be far slower and less of a guaranteed store than running CrashPlan.
> With CrashPlan running at both ends, the destination software simulates restores and validates files when the destination is idle and not in use. This is a big deal - something you cannot do with FTP efficiently - and ensures that your files are in good shape when you need them

Comment: Thank you! Obviously I should have looked in the FAQ before posting here -- my bad.